# appendCommitMessageToRunName: false for classic AzureDevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Yaml AzureDevOps pipeline, we can set :

```
appendCommitMessageToRunName: false
```

By default the commit message is append to the build number. If false, nothing is append to the build number.

How to do the same in a **classic** AzureDevOps pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

After checking the [Sprint 209 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/pipelines/sprint-209-update?tabs=yaml#disable-showing-the-last-commit-message-for-a-pipeline-run), it seems this function only applies to the Yaml pipeline now.

> We heard your feedback from the Developer Community asking us for a way to enable/disable appending the latest commit message to the title of every pipeline run. With this update, we've added a new YAML property, named `appendCommitMessageToRunName`, that lets you do exactly that. By
> default, the property is set to true. When you set it to false, the pipeline run will only display the BuildNumber.

You can request the feature for classic Azure DevOps pipeline in  [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest).